# How to validate years dynamically using validators in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to validate that the year entered must be less than or equals to the current year. I am using server side validators in ASP.Net and C#, and all validators are inside a validator group. So please suggest me to validate one more condition within the same.

Thanks
Amit Ranjan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ASP.NET CompareValidator.

For e.g. if you have a TextBox with id TextBox1, which accepts a year in 'yyyy' format, then you can do the following:

```
Year: 
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  &nbsp;
<asp:CompareValidator id="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
  Operator="LessThan" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Year must 
  be less than current year" Type="Integer"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Add this to code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     CompareValidator1.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Today.Year; 
}
```

Also remember using validators won't stop a Submit; use these in conjunction with ValidationSummary Control.

More on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9h59855(v=vs.80).aspx